# calling generic method multiple times with different parameters

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

Is there a way to make this code more optimized, so I have a generic method that process all the logic and it accepts the few parameters and then it adds the key/value to the object `displayData`

I'm repeating multiple times to call the `myGenericMethod` with different parameters, any thing that I can improve based on what I have here?

my generic method:

```
displayData = {};
myGenericMethod(param1, param2, param3) {
      //do something with parameters.....
      //.....get the data from db....
      //processed data
      //finally adding the 
      displayData[param1] = processed data
      displayData[param2] = processed data
      //.....
}
```

//call the `myGenericMethod`

```
this.myGenericMethod('aaa','bbb','ccc');
this.myGenericMethod('ddd','eee','eee');
this.myGenericMethod('fff','fff','fff');
this.myGenericMethod('ggg','ggg','ggg');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) or [Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to call the function. Here's an example with Function.prototype.apply:

```
[ ['aaa','bbb','ccc'], ['ddd','eee','eee'], ['fff','fff','fff'], ['ggg','ggg','ggg'] ]
  .forEach(params => this.myGenericMethod.apply(this, params))
```

The difference between the two is that apply accepts a list of parameters (as we're doing here), while call takes individual parameters.

In either case, we specify `this` as the first parameter, which sets the `this` inside the function call; we need this to access our controller's properties.